# When Check Box in RecyclerView is Selected,more than one Check Box is Selected also

Tags: android

In my application I used RecyclerView , contains text View and Check Box, But when one Check Box is Selected,more than one Check Box is Selected also 
, I found questions similar to this situation in the site, I actually tried to implement them to solve my problem but I could not because there is some difference with code and here it is :

class RecyclerView_dAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<List_Item> list_items;
private List<List_Item> favorite_itemes = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

RecyclerView_dAdapter(List<List_Item> list_Item, Context context) {
    list_items = list_Item;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public RecyclerView_dAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView_dAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    List_Item current = list_items.get(position);
    final String name = current.getName();

    holder.TextName.setText(name);
    holder.TextName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Show_Team_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("TeamName", name);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v;

            if (chk.isChecked()) {               
                favorite_itemes.add(list_items.get(pos));
                chk.setChecked(true);
            } else if (!chk.isChecked()) {                   
                favorite_itemes.remove(list_items.get(pos));
                chk.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return list_items.size();        
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView TextName;
    private CheckBox favorite_checkBox;
    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        TextName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_rowitem);
        favorite_checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_checkBox);
        favorite_checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic) {
        this.itemClickListener = ic;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because RecyclerView recycles views. Add this piece of code in your onBindViewHolder method:

```
holder.favorite_checkBox.setChecked(favorite_itemes.contains(current));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain your checkbox states.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView_dAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    List_Item current = list_items.get(position);
    final String name = current.getName();

    holder.TextName.setText(name);
    holder.TextName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Show_Team_Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("TeamName", name);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 //set check boxes state
 holder.favorite_checkBox.setChecked(favorite_itemes.contains(current))

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v;

            if (chk.isChecked()) {               
                favorite_itemes.add(list_items.get(pos));
                //chk.setChecked(true);
            } else if (!chk.isChecked()) {                   
                favorite_itemes.remove(list_items.get(pos));
                //chk.setChecked(false);
            }
            //notify changes
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });

}
```